# Filtering layer of OpenStreetMap data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, query, filter

I have a table osm_roads that has a column named *geometry* geometry geometry(LineString,900913).

If I want to filter a city to draw districts, I cannot do it by geographic coordinates.

What if in QGIS I want to select by bounding box, such a table as that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do the **bounding box** you need a polygon of the city in the same coordinate system as your current data

Go to either Vector>Research Tools->Select by location or Plugins>Spatial Query and select the options.

Vector>Research Tools->Polygon from layer extent and make a polygon of the full extent. Then follow the steps in option 1 above using your new polygon.